# Install multiple appliances

Tags: drupal-6, lamp, turnkeylinux.org

I just installed [Turnkey LAMP Stack Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp), and I need to install Drupal, Redmine and a few more appliances, I read the documentation but did not understand how to install them on the same server, the documentation said to install them as a virtual machine, but *that doesn't mean that I will have a LAMP instalation for every applicances (different Apache/PHP/mysql configuration) ?*

I try to install drupal6 via Webmine (dpkg) didn't work, I installed via apt-get and worked, but can't find any link to the "Drupal Administration interface" in webmine :(.

So the question's are:

***There is a way of instaling multile appliances on the same server sharing the same LAMP instalation, or I need to instal them via WM, and configure LAMP for each instalarion ?***
***How would you install them ?***

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a way of instaling multile
>   appliances on the same server sharing
>   the same LAMP instalation, or I need
>   to instal them via WM, and configure
>   LAMP for each instalarion? How would
>   you install them?

TurnKey Linux Appliance is easy-to-use one-purpose solution which you can *deploy in minutes on bare metal, virtual machines, or in the cloud*. It contains nice *web management interface, web shell, and simple configuration console*, is lightweight (~150MB each, no redundant packages preinstalled) and secure, but it is basically tuned Ubuntu 10.04 LTS ([quotes are from TKL site](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/benefits)).

To sum up it's just Ubuntu with LAMP and some goodies preinstalled, so if you want to deploy more than one application on one machine (no matter virtual or bare metal) **you'll have to install Drupal, Webmine and other packages manually (probably using `apt-get`), configure them and Apache's VirtualHosts etc. as Charter wrote and you pointed out in comment**.

So where is TKL strenght you ask? It's in [virtualization](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/virtualization). In your case you want to deploy Drupal, Webmine and for expample MySQL Appliances. You have one server and three appliances then. On your server you install some free bare metal full-virtualization hypervisor (could be [VMWare ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/esxi-and-esx/index.html) or [Proxmox VE](http://www.proxmox.com/products/proxmox-ve) or Linux host with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) installed, then you create three VMs on you virtualization platform and install each of them configuring them as you want (main configuraion of Drupal / Webmine / MySQL is from TKL), configure VMs network so they can be accessed from Web, and you finish with three separate server environments, each dedicated for one purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add virtual host to your apache2 config using webmin. Here is a link explaining how to do that : http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Name-BasedVirtualHosting.

Comment: I understand that you are sugesting to install them as in any other LAMP server without any help from TurnKey ? I always did that but I wanted to give TurnKey, if I fall back to apt-get for every new applicance ... how is TurnKey helping me, why is easier ? I think I'm missing something when using TurnKey :)

Answer (score 0):

In general you would do better to install different Turnkey Aps, ie different server images, for each application you want to install.  You can use Lamp to install multiple on a single machine and IP address but then you get far less portability than you have with the individual installed aps.  Portability is the key.  If you want to migrate to the next version of Debian, you would use TKLBAM to backup the old Debian install, and install the Latest Image base of Debian Machine, then run TKLBAM-RESTORE moving your old data forward.

Concievably you could make a migratable ap with multiple elements that would also migrate forward.  Your Backup images get quite large if you simply do this manually on LAMP.  Particularly valuable with the individual aps is the fact that you don't have to run down all the source images, install them variously with WGET, BZR, SVN etc.  You simply install and run.

To be effective with all this though you should have some system for running multiple VM's.  VmWare, ProMox, Etc all work.  Also the TurnKey Amazon method is very easy.  Runnin on Amazon there would be some argument for A LAMP install with multiple aps just to control your costs, but you will need RAM and HD Space so the equation needs some calculation.